# Not awaiting nested promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs

It should be noted that I am pretty new to all of this asynchronous stuff.

I am trying to wait until the existence of a file is verified, whereby the script creates the file if need be, before updating the file. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

I know that I can use `fs.writeFileSync`, but I would prefer to make it asynchronous, so to guarantee that it does not block any user activity.

```
// this is now detectDriveInfo(), the entire function unedited, verbatim
async function detectDriveInfo(){
  const exec = require('child_process').exec
  let
    totalFreespace = 0,
    totalSize = 0,
    drives = []
  exec('wmic logicaldisk get freespace,name,size,volumename', (error, stdout)=>{
    stdout
      .trim()
      .split('\r\r\n')
      .map(value => value.trim().split(/\s{2,}/))
      .slice(1)
      .sort((a,b) => Number(a[0]) - Number(b[0]))
      .forEach(async (value, i, a) => {
        renderDriveInfo(...value)
        totalFreespace += Number(value[0])
        totalSize += Number(value[2])
        drives.push([value[1], Number(value[2]) - Number(value[0])])
        if (i === a.length-1) {
          renderDriveInfo(totalFreespace,'ALL',totalSize,'')
          updateConfigDrives(drives)
          await guaranteeData(drives) // this and its nested promises have to happen/complete
          updateData(drives)          // before this
        }
      })
  })
}

async function guaranteeData(drives){
  const fs = require('fs')
  if (!fs.existsSync('./data.json')) {
    let json = {}
    drives = drives.map(([v]) => v)
    drives.forEach(v => {
      json[v] = []
    })
    json = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
    await fs.writeFile('./data.json', json, 'utf8', (error)=>{
      if (error) throw error
      console.log('The file, data.json, has been created.')
      console.log(json)
    })
    return
  }
}
```

Console Logs

```
1. should come last
2. The file, data.json, has been created.
3. {
  "C:": [],
  "G:": [],
  "K:": [],
  "D:": [],
  "E:": [],
  "H:": [],
  "J:": [],
  "I:": [],
  "F:": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re mixing callbacks and promises. The callback version of `fs.writeFile` returns `undefined`, which unfortunately is a value JavaScript will be perfectly happy to `await` for you (by not waiting for anything at all).

Use `fs.promises.writeFile` from the [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) with no callback:

```
await fs.promises.writeFile('data.json', json, 'utf8')
console.log('The file, data.json, has been created.')
console.log(json)
```

You’ll probably also want to [specify that the file should never be overwritten](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags), in case it’s created between the existence check and the write:

```
await fs.promises.writeFile('data.json', json, {
  flag: 'wx',
  encoding: 'utf8',
})
```

Then use the non-synchronous equivalent of `fs.existsSync`:

```
if (await fs.promises.access('data.json', fs.constants.F_OK)
            .catch(err => err.code === 'ENOENT' || Promise.reject(err))) {
```

Or just skip the existence check entirely and rely on `wx` if creating the JSON isn’t too expensive.

`forEach` with an `async` action is always wrong, too, because `forEach` discards whatever its action returns, and the return value of an async function is critical. You need a regular loop to run serially, although it’s unclear where `drives` comes from:

```
for (const value of stdout) {
  // ??
}

await guaranteeData(drives)
console.log('should come last')
// updateData(drives)
```

Finally, a promise version of `exec` is required for `detectDriveInfo()` to resolve correctly. Right now the promise it returns doesn’t wait for the operation to complete either.

Comment: i removed a lot of logic from the `forEach/if` blocks for the sake of simplifying my q. man, `forEach` is so much more convenient than `for/of` just because it carries the `index` value by default

Comment: @oldboy: Is it really convenient if it completely doesn’t work? `for (const [i, value] of stdout.entries())`.

Comment: no, i guess its not. i didnt know u could do that with `for/of`. is the `.entries()` necessary?

Comment: @oldboy: Yes. `.entries()` is a method on arrays that returns an iterator of its `[index, value]` pairs.

Comment: @oldboy: Check file exists → write to file is a common mistake, because the file can be created by a different process after you make the check but before you write the file. Even if it won’t happen with this tool, the correct version is cleaner anyway (the whole complicated `fs.promises.access` thing, you can just get rid of entirely with `flags: 'wx'`).

Comment: did you suggest the `fsp.access` as an alternative to the `fs.existsSync` in the parent `if` block in my current code? the `wx` flag is nice :)

Comment: @oldboy: Yep. (`fs.exists` is deprecated, so it doesn’t exist on the promise API, hence why I couldn’t just write `if (!await fs.promises.exists('data.json'))`.)

Comment: `fs.exists` is deprecated, but [`fs.existsSync` is not](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) ?

Comment: @oldboy: Yeah, `fs.exists` doesn’t use an `(err, exists)` callback, just `(exists)`. The sync version doesn’t have that problem since it doesn’t have a callback.

Comment: man that `wx` flag is amazing. so, depending on my script/the structure thereof, theres really no reason at all to even check if the file exists if i use `wx`, right?

Comment: @oldboy: Right, if your concern was not overwriting an existing file. (If you want to ignore the error from an existing file, you need to add something like `.catch(err => err.code === 'EEXIST' || Promise.reject(err))`, or a `try`/`catch` if you find that more readable.

Comment: my only concern was avoiding unforeseen errors by attempting to write to or read from a specific key/value pair in a JSON file that does not exist since the structure is created dynamically. one last thing, im not really awaiting anything to be returned from `guaranteeData()`, the only requirement is that `console.log('should come last')` only executes after `guaranteeData()` and all of the code therein finishes executing, so does it really matter if i use `async` with the `forEach` ??

Comment: @oldboy: Yes, there’s no guarantee that “should come last” will come last with a `forEach` that looks like that. If you don’t care about the order of execution, you can use `map` instead and wrap the result in `await Promise.all()` (i.e. `stdout.forEach(async …)` becomes `await Promise.all(stdout.map(async …))`). (Or, if you want to keep using a callback there and whatever calls `detectDriveInfo` doesn’t wait for it, remove the `await` and make `detectDriveInfo` not an async function. Then you can add a `.catch()` to the `Promise.all()` if you don’t want any errors to go unhandled.)

Comment: why is there no guarantee? you said it **"discards"** what the promise returns. did you mean **'disregards'**?? i really only need `updateData(drives)` to `await` the completion of `guaranteeData(drives)` and everything therewithin in the very last iteration of the `forEach` loop.

Comment: @oldboy: I think those words mean the same thing here? It doesn’t do anything with the promise each call returns. It calls them all at the same time. The call corresponding to the last element doesn’t necessarily complete its task first. If you use `await` in a `for`…`of` loop, the loop pauses and every task runs to completion by itself, in order. If you use `Promise.all` and `map`, the tasks all happen at the same time in no particular order like with `forEach`, but you *do* get a promise that resolves when all tasks have completed in the end.

Comment: @oldboy: The returned value *is* the promise. `async (value, i, a) => { … }` is a function that returns a promise.

Comment: @oldboy: If you’re only `await`ing once in the last iteration, `forEach` is fine, but the action you pass to it should not be async.

Comment: ok i finally understand what youre saying now. so basically a `forEach(async` behaves like `Promise.all`. i dont know what u mean by the action i pass to the `forEach` ?? here ill update my code to show you what i removed from the `detectDrivesInfo()` chain

Comment: @oldboy: No :P `forEach(async` is literally always wrong. When people use it, they typically mean `Promise.all(arr.map(async` or `for (const x of arr)`. This is one of the cases where you meant neither of those, but `forEach(async` is still not correct.

Comment: i updated the code in my Q. u still think i need to swap it to a `for/of` loop to guarantee the order of those two things in the very last iteration?

Comment: `for (const [i, value] of stdout.entries())` is telling me `stdout.entries is not a function or its return value is not iterable` ??

Comment: @oldboy https://gist.github.com/minitech/f0aeeb145b886541efba9c767f301eab

Comment: ok [heres what i created](https://gist.github.com/gtkpr/9f77587b8732df3cf7d1bde6114dcbca) based on your feedback, which seems to be working. man, i dont know why this is so incredibly tough for me to understand. learning to write asynchronous code feels as difficult for me as learning js when i first started learning js. it doesnt help that ill code for weeks/months, then stop for weeks/months, so on and so forth. whats really throwing me off about your gist is `ignoreExist`, doesnt `fsp.writeFile` already return a promise? couldnt it just be `created = fsp.writeFile(...); if (created) ...`?

Comment: @oldboy: It does already return a promise, but one that resolves to `undefined` if it succeeds and throws if it fails (including if the file already exists). `ignoreExist` takes a promise and returns a new one where it converts success into `true` (was created), failure with the error `EEXIST` into `false` (was not created), and failure with other errors into a rejection.

Comment: you could hypothetically turn `guaranteeData()` into [this](https://gist.github.com/gtkpr/c15379cb06ec346433b24a10eed617c9), right? like there aren't any issues with [this](https://gist.github.com/gtkpr/c15379cb06ec346433b24a10eed617c9)? for some reason, none of these variations including `ignoreExist` seem to throw an error when the file already exists ?

Comment: @oldboy: Yes, that code would work the same as the `ignoreExist` one. None of the variations throw an error when the file already exists, because… that’s exactly what they’re written to avoid (to match the behaviour of the previous `existsSync` check). If you want to throw an error, there’s no need for any of the catching or conditionals, just `await fsp.writeFile(…)` and do nothing with the return value.

Comment: hmm then whats the point of checking for the error code `err.code === 'EEXIST'` if its never going to be thrown?

Comment: even if i change `return false` to `throw error` and the file exists, it still doesnt throw the error tho?

Comment: @oldboy: Well, it should… if it’s not ending up as an unhandled rejection, I’m not sure what’s going on.

Comment: youre right. its all good now. thanks a ton for your all of your help buddy <33

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code , i would suggest using a modern `for … of` loop instead, in which await will work as expected :

```
for (const value of stdout) {
  // Inside this await will work as you aspecting
}
```

Comment: `forEach` is just so nice how it carries the `idx` by default and how i can also just chain it together with everything else. thanks for your input tho